# How to decode a QR-code which is in PDF file made by paper scanning with "zbar bar code reader"

Tags: pdf, qr-code, zbar

I can decode a PDF's QR-code made by PDF PRINT DRIVER
(as like PrimoPDF http://primopdf.en.softonic.com/).

However, I CANNOT decode a PDF's QR-code made by PAPER SCANNING, and get the following message as...
WARNING: barcode data was not detected in some image(s)
**_*thing to check:

_*___**- is the barcode type supported? currently supported symbologies are:
**____***EAN/UPC(EAN-13, EAN-8, UPC-A, UPC-E, ISBN-10, ISBN-13),*

___*Code 128, Code 39 and Interleaved 2 of 5*

__*- is the barcode large enough in the image?*

__*- is the bacode mostly in focus?*

___- is there sufficient contrast/illumination?

I don't think it is due to resolution because the QR-code is scanned by 400dpi.
Please tell me what to do.

Comment: Please consider providing sample PDFs with QR codes you cannot scan.

Comment: I uploaded the two PDF files (successed one & falid one) <br><https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4ZIiPJrEU6_eFczSUVnNHNNLUU/edit?usp=sharing><br>
<https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4ZIiPJrEU6_eVk2aW5qaEo2UFk/edit?usp=sharing>

Answer (score 0):

> I don't think it is due to resolution because the QR-code is scanned by 400dpi.

It is not the resolution, it is the quality of the scanned document.

If you look at the (somewhat enlarged) working sample, you see black areas where the QR is black and white areas where it is white:

[image: sucsessed_symbol_is_a_letter_of_a.pdf screenshot]

On the other hand, if you look at the failing sample, you see a mixture of black and white spots where the QR is black:

[image]

Thus, it is no surprise that your barcode recognition software fails.

As I don't know the quality of the paper printouts which you scan and the options your scanner offers, it is hard to say whether the scanning process as such can be improved to provide recognizable QR codes.

It might be worth a try, though, to pre-process the scanned image, using some image processor that removes noise pixels.